# Results from 3 tables in SQL (PHP OR SQL solution needed)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have 3 tables: **product**, **store** and **product_store**.

I want to show that **one product** can be found in **many stores**. But at the same time not show the product more than once. Solution in **SQL**, **PHP** or maybe even Jquery.

```
CREATE TABLE product (
  name varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  product_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (product_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE store (
  store_id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  store_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (store_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE store_product (
  store_id int NOT NULL,
  product_id int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (store_id, product_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES product (product_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES store (store_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

To show the results in SQL:

```
SELECT name, store_name 
   FROM product p 
      LEFT JOIN store_product sp ON p.product_id = sp.product_id
      INNER JOIN store s ON s.store_id = sp.store_id;
```

Giving the following result :

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DccNK.png)

But really I want the following result:

[Wanted result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKjn0.png)

Is there a solution in **SQL or PHP** for my problem? Could it be done with using arrays or something like that? Off course it has to be so flexible so it can be 1 store or 3 stores or perhaps so much as 7 stores.

Online it should appear something like:

```
**Computer**
Can be found in Computer-Shop, Computer-Store...
```

Very thankful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL GROUP_CONCAT() function](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

> ```sql
> SELECT name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.store_name,",") AS store_name    FROM
> product p 
>       LEFT JOIN store_product sp ON p.product_id = sp.product_id
>       INNER JOIN store s ON s.store_id = sp.store_id GROUP BY name;
> ```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Thanks for your advices. I re-edit this answer, please review it.